# possible to GET parameters when you have POST the parameters?

Tags: php, url, post, parameters, get

i used a form to **POST** the parameters to categories.php

```
<form action="categories.php" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Filter Categories</legend>
    <p>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="music"/> Music</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="technology"/> Technology</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="film"/> Film</label>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">Filter</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

So if I would to filter Music and Film the URL would look like:

http://domain.com/categories.php`?categories[]=music&categories[]=film`

the parameters will be hidden since i used POST and thats how i want it i don't want to see the parameters BUT....i have some links in my site that link to single categories i.e.

---

### Categories:

Music (links to [http://domain.com/categories.php?categories[]=music](http://domain.com/categories.php?categories%5b%5d=music))

Film (links to [http://domain.com/categories.php?categories[]=film](http://domain.com/categories.php?categories%5b%5d=film))

now when someone visits the categories.php page trough an URL like that it will give me errors because i USED POST and not GET now how will i be able to GET those parameters still?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is the problem when using POST to show the user some content.

It is impossible to bookmark or create a link so they can see it again without posting the same POST data every time.

Why is it that you don't want your users to be able to see the search terms on their address bar?

Since it's not a security problem I'm assuming it's because those links don't look good, in which case I'd point you to start using [clean urls](http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls).